# What Java Components will suffice the need..?

Tags: java, swing

My application will be similar to MS Compiled HTML Help Viewer. On the left side, I will be using `JList` and on the right side, a `JTextPane` containing long text files.

I have done upto this, but now, quite confused which component to use for displaying the a Dialog box which will be for searching the words in the displayed text files. I tried `JDialog`
but with `DISPOSE_ON_EXIT`.

I select any word to find its next occurence, I just pass it to the `JDialog` as a global parameter and do the process. After this I close the `JDialog`. And when the same process is done for another word, the `JDialog` just doesnt take the new second word, it works with the first word only... What I am doing wrong... ??? Any solution..??? Thanks in advance

EDIT -

This is the code for JDialog with defaultCloseOperation as DISPOSE (NetBeans)-

```
public class Search extends JDialog
{
   public Search(JFrame parent, boolean modal, String sWords)
   {
       super(parent, modal);
       initComponents();
       setTitle("Search for - " + sWords);
       //Searching procedure
```

Now when the user copies some text and invokes this form I pass this selected word to the Search JDialog as -

```
   Search s = new Search(parent, true, selectedWord);
```

Comment: Can you show the dialog code? That would make diagnosing the problem easier

Comment: I am simply passing a parameter to the constructor `public Search(JFrame parent, boolean modal, String sWord) { super(parent, modal); initComponents(); ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use [`JOptionPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html):

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World!");
panel.add(label); // You can add any components you want to this panel

 pane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "JOptionPane Title", 
     JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, 
     null, new Object[]{}, null);
```

Comment: The search form which I am talking about is a full search form with various options like MatchCase, IgnoreCase, and certain more options. So will it be possible with JOptionPane..?

Comment: @John Yes, it is possible. You can add `JCheckBox`, `JLabel`, `JTextFiled` ... etc, into a `JPanel` and pass it as 2nd parameter of `showOptionDialog()` method.